# JQuery Search multiple columns in table

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I found this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/rFGWZ/

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();

$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

        $row = $(this);

        var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

        if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
            $row.hide();
        }
        else {
            $row.show();
        }
    }
});
});
```

where JQuery is being used to filter and search the first column of the table. I've been trying to modify this so it searches ALL columns regardless of how many columns the table has.

Can this be done or do I have to know the amount of columns beforehand?

P.S. - I'm trying to avoid data tables since I don't need all the extra functionality that comes with it.

Comment: you can use data table instead of create new code...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using data tables. I don't need all the extra functionality that comes with it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it wasn't that difficult. Here's what I modified:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
        $row = $(this);

        $row.find('td').each (function() {
            var id = $(this).text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
                return false;
            }
        });  

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check the whole row of on every column you don't need to use .find("td: first") just use plain .text() and I think the indexOf() return -1 if not found.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                $row.show();    
            }
            else {
                $row.hide();    
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't this lead to false positives? Example use value 446 there isnt a td that matches 446 4 is the last digit of unique id and 46 is the 1st two digits on the random id http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/1s8nhg9h/

Comment: You're right, I missed that! Sticking with my solution I guess.

Comment: well you are right I didn't thought about that, anyway how about using .html() instead of .text() although it will include <td></td> inside the var id it will act as a separator for each column.

Answer (score 1):

Use Filter to find matches of td. Then check length to make sure one exists.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            var $row = $(this);
            //Filter down tds which inner text matches indexOf check
            var matches = $row.find('td').filter(function(ix,item){
                return $(item).text().indexOf(value) > -1;
            });

                        //if matches exist then show else hide
            if (matches.length != 0) {
                $row.show();    
            }
            else {
                $row.hide();    
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/wa6q6Lnr/

Answer (score 0):

Data table can full fill the requirement 
check here

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html